# $G\times H \cong G \times K$ implies $H\cong K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G,~H,~K$ be groups satisfying both ACC and DCC. Prove that $$G\times H \cong G \times K\Longrightarrow H\cong K$$
>
> Prove also that $G^n \cong H^n$ implies that $G \cong H$.

---

By Krull-Schmidt theorem, $$G=G_1\times ...\times G_n,~H=H_1\times ...\times H_p,~K=K_1\times ...\times K_q$$ with indecomposable subgroups. If $\phi$ is an isomorphism $$\phi:~~G\times H \to G\times K$$ then $$\phi(G\times H)=\phi(G_1)\times...\times\phi(G_n)\times\phi(H_1)\times...\times\phi(H_p)$$ $$=G_1\times ...\times G_n\times K_1\times ...\times K_q=G\times K.$$

Then, what's the next step? And is second problem similar?

Answer (score 0):

Is it true?

$G\times H$ also satisfies ACC and DCC

Let $H_1<H_2<...$ be chain of normal subgroups of $G\times H$

Consider $\pi(H_i)$ and {$e$}$\times H \cap H_i$ where $\pi$ is a projection map of $G\times H$ into $G$ and $i=1,2,3,...$

Since $G,H$ satisfy both chain condition, above sequences must stop

i.e. $\exists N$ s.t. $n\ge N$ then $\pi(H_n)=\pi(H_N)$ and {$e$}$\times H \cap H_n$={$e$}$\times H \cap H_N$ (Since we can consider {$e$}$\times H \cap H_i$ as a subgroup of $H$)

Then $H_n=H_N$ as following

$x\in H_n \Rightarrow \pi(x)\in\pi(H_n)=\pi(H_N)\Rightarrow \exists y\in H_N$ s.t. $\pi(y)=\pi(x)$

$x-y\in ker(\pi)$={$e$}$\times H$$\Rightarrow x,y\in H_n , x-y\in${$e$}$\times H$$\Rightarrow x-y\in${$e$}$\times H \cap H_n$={$e$}$\times H \cap H_N$

$x-y\in H_N$, $y\in H_N$ $\Rightarrow x\in H_N$

So $G\times H$ satisfies ACC and DCC is similar