# What is wrong with the followig proof that $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, integers, group-isomorphism

Since

$ G =( \prod_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z} )\times  \mathbb{Z}  \times \mathbb{Z}  \cong (\prod_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{Z}  $,

by taking quotients we get

$\mathbb{Z \times Z} \cong G/ \prod_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore

$\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z \times Z}$.

But $\mathbb{Z}$ is indecomposable!  What's wrong with above proof?

Comment: You are not working within a field structure. This you can't use cancellation.

Comment: What's so special about $\mathbb Z$? Haven't you just proved $G\cong G\times G$ for **every** group $G$? If $G$ is a group of order $n$, does that mean that $n^2=n$ for every $n$?

Comment: The isomorphism from $(\prod \mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to $(\prod\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{Z}$ does not map $(\prod\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$ to $(\prod\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}$; so you do not know that you are taking quotients modulo "the same thing"; that is, you have an isomorphism $\phi\colon G\to K$; and subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ and $M\triangleleft K$ with $N\cong M$; but unless $\phi(N)=M$, you cannot use $\phi$ to conclude $G/N\cong K/M$; yet you are trying to do so here.

Comment: This is basically the same as arguing $\infty +1 = \infty$; subtracting $\infty$ from both sides, $1=0$.

Answer (score 6):

Quotienting by isomorphic copy need not preserve isomorphisms.  For a simpler related example: $C_n=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}\cong n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $m,n>0$, but obviously the cyclic groups $C_m$ and $C_n$ are not isomorphic if $m\neq n$.

Comment: Quotient here is not by isomorphic copy. I am using the fact that factors are normal subgroups, and then using the first isomorphism theorem.  The example you gave has no such product structure.

Comment: @student: If you are not using an isomorphic copy, then it is wrong to write $G/ \prod_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$, because you only have $G \cong (\prod_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{Z}$, not $G = (\prod_{1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}) \times \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I think that might be it, but I can't see the subtlety here. What's the difference between $=$ and $\cong$ here? If I have $G\cong H \times K$, can i not say $G/H \cong K$? Why, an example?

Comment: @student: You already know an example: the one you found in your question!

Comment: @student: If you have $\varphi\colon G\xrightarrow{\cong}H\times K$, then $G/\varphi^{-1}(H\times\{1\})\cong K$.  However, if you have $\psi\colon H\hookrightarrow G$ or even $\psi\colon H\times K'\xrightarrow{\cong}G$, there is no reason to expect $G/\varphi(H\times\{1\})$ and $G/\psi(H)$ to be isomorphic or even one to be a homomorphic image of the other.

Comment: An example is $G=(C_2)^\omega\times(C_3)^\omega$, where you have $(C_2)^\alpha\times(C_3)^{\beta}$ for every $\alpha,\beta\leq\omega$ as the complement (and quotient) of an isomorphic copy of $G$ in $G$, since $n+\omega=2\omega=\omega$ for all $n<\omega$, but clearly there are no nontrivial homomorphism between $C_2$ and $C_3$.

Comment: However, under some stringent conditions, [$G\times H\cong G\times K$ implies $H\cong K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724232/g-times-h-cong-g-times-k-implies-h-cong-k?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is based on the assumption that $G/N_1\cong G/N_2$ follows from $N_1\cong N_2$. Since $\mathbb Z\not\cong\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$, your example shows that the assumption is incorrect. Here is a simpler example.

The non-isomorphic groups $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ are both homomorphic images of the group $G=\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_4$. Thus there are subgroups $N_1,N_2$ of $G$ such that $G/N_1\cong\mathbb Z_4$ and $G/N_2\cong\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$. The subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ are isomorphic, as they are groups of order $2$;
so $N_1\cong N_2$ but $G/N_1\not\cong G/N_2$.

**P.S.** In other words (considering your comment on another answer, "If I have $G\cong H\times K$, can i not say $G/H\cong K$?"): here we have $G\cong N_2\times\mathbb Z_4$, but $G/N_2\not\cong\mathbb Z_4$.